# two submit button in one form

Tags: jsp, struts2

I've got one form linked to an action, and two submit buttons: the first one, `"aggiungiSocietà"`, adds a Society on the html page (with the js function addRow()) and sends the values inserted to the action...of course, I can add more than one society;
the second one, `"applicaFinal"`, sends all the values inserted on the page.

My problem is: I want the first button to send also all of the previous values inserted (via Struts), but I can't do it even if it's inside the same Struts form. Meanwhile, `"applicaFinal"` doesn't send the values related to the inserted societies, only the last one inserted.
Can someone explain how to resolve this big issue? Im open to change the logic of my code too, if it doesn't make a lot of sense for someone.

(I'll post a small part of the .jsp code, without the 20+ options and fields to insert in the page)

```
<s:form cssClass="form-validate-jquery" action="DichiarazioniAction"
        id="DichiarazioniForm" name="DichiarazioniForm"
        onsubmit="return addRow();">
<div class="form-group">
                    <s:radio cssClass="styledRadios" name="optionsRadios4_06"
                        id="optionsRadios4_06" onclick="tab4_06chk00(this.value)"
                        list="#{'Si':'S&Iacute','No':'NO'}" required="required" />
                </div>

                <!-- Table4_00 sez4 -->
                <div id="tab4_00sez4"
                    <s:if test='optionsRadios4_06.equals("") || optionsRadios4_06.equals("No")'>style="display: none;"</s:if>>
                    <!-- Tabella -->
                    <br>
                    <table id="table" class="table datatable-basic">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Denominazione</th>
                            <th>Sede</th>
                            <th>P.IVA</th>
                            <th>Codice Fiscale</th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>

                        <tbody id="tableInsert">
                            <s:iterator value="listaSocietà" var="theSocietà"
                                status="status1">
                                <s:set var="società-%{#status1.index}" value="theSocietà"
                                    scope="session" />
                                <tr>
                                    <td><s:property value="denominazione" /></td>
                                    <td><s:property value="sede" /></td>
                                    <td><s:property value="partitaIVA" /></td>
                                    <td><s:property value="codiceFiscale" /></td>
                                    <td><div align="right">
                                            <div class="btn-group btn-group-xs">
                                                <s:submit type="button" name="eliminaSocietà"
                                                    id="eliminaSocietà" value="%{#status1.index}"
                                                    data-toggle="tooltip" title="Elimina"
                                                    cssClass="btn btn-default">
                                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                                                </s:submit>
                                            </div>
                                        </div></td>
                                </tr>
                            </s:iterator>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <!-- Button trigger modal società controllate/collegate -->
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"
                        data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalHorizontal">Inserisci
                        nuova societ&agrave</button>
                    <div id="prova"></div>
                    <br> <br>
                    <!-- Modal inserimento Società Controllate/Collegate -->
                    <div class="modal large" id="myModalHorizontal" tabindex="-1"
                        role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <!-- Modal Header -->
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span> <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                                    </button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Inserisci
                                        Societ&agrave</h4>
                                </div>

                                <!-- Modal Body -->
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        Denominazione: <span class="text-danger"> <b> * </b> </span>
                                        <s:textfield name="tab4_04fld01" id="tab4_04fld01"
                                            cssClass="form-control"
                                            placeholder="Inserire qui la denominazione" />
                                        <div id="errorDenominazione" style="display: none;">
                                            <span class="text-danger">Campo obbligatorio</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                Sede: <span class="text-danger"> <b> * </b> </span>
                                                <s:textfield name="tab4_04fld02" id="tab4_04fld02"
                                                    Class="form-control" placeholder="Inserire qui la sede" />
                                                <div id="errorSede" style="display: none;">
                                                    <span class="text-danger">Campo obbligatorio</span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                P.IVA: <span class="text-danger"> <b> * </b> </span>
                                                <s:textfield name="tab4_04fld03" id="tab4_04fld03"
                                                    Class="form-control"
                                                    placeholder="Inserire qui la partita IVA" />
                                                <div id="errorP_IVA" style="display: none;">
                                                    <span class="text-danger">Campo obbligatorio
                                                        (Inserire 11 cifre)</span>
                                                </div>
                                                <div id="uniqueP_IVA" style="display: none;">
                                                    <span class="text-danger">Partita IVA gi&agrave
                                                        inserita</span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                Codice Fiscale: <span class="text-danger"> <b> *
                                                </b> </span>
                                                <s:textfield name="tab4_04fld04" id="tab4_04fld04"
                                                    Class="form-control"
                                                    placeholder="Inserire qui il codice fiscale" />
                                                <div id="errorCF" style="display: none;">
                                                    <span class="text-danger">Campo obbligatorio
                                                        (Inserire un Codice Fiscale valido)</span>
                                                </div>
                                                <div id="uniqueCF" style="display: none;">
                                                    <span class="text-danger">Codice Fiscale gi&agrave
                                                        inserito</span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="btn-group">
                                        <div>
                                            <div style="width: 100%;">
                                                <button type="submit" name="aggiungiSocietà"
                                                    id="aggiungiSocietà" value="aggiungiSocietà"
                                                    class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded"
                                                    style="float: left; background-color: #455A64; border-color: #455A64;"
                                                    onclick="addRow()">
                                                    <i class="icon-pen-plus position-left"></i>Aggiungi
                                                </button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Tabella end-->
                </div>
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div align="center" style="margin-top: 50px;">
                        <!-- <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default" id="reset">
                                Reset <i class="icon-reload-alt position-right"></i>
                            </button> -->
                        <button type="submit" name="applicaFinal" value="applicaFinal"
                            class="btn bg-romaCapitale">
                            Applica <i class="icon-pen6 position-right"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</s:form>
```

Comment: Do you want the first button to do the same as the second button? Just remove the first button.

Comment: @RomanC no. I want this: everytime I click `"aggiungiSocietà"`, I want to send the four fields of the society I've just inserted, to the action...BUT, at the same time, because this button is a submit and it refreshes the page, I also want to save all of the previous fields not related to the society (for example `"optionsRadios4_06"`, in some way. Otherwise,because of the refresh, those fields would be blank and the user would be obligated to write all again.

Comment: updated the answer

Comment: Not. The values are pre-populated after the result execution. You only need to provide getters to the control tags.

Comment: "You only need to provide getters to the control tags"
What do you mean with that?

Answer (score 0):

Request sessions are persistent only for the last submit. Hence, you'd lose the values of previous submits, but retain the latest one only (which is actually happening in your case).

**Solution 1**

If you want to send the previously submitted values of "Society" as well, I'd suggest create "hidden" inputs along with your table update after every "aggiungiSocietà" submit. Include below in your iterator which lists all the rows currently inserted

```
 <input type="hidden" name="varname%{status1.count}" value="varvalue">
```

After this, even "applicaFinal" submit button should send all the previously added rows. This is because these hidden inputs are visible to this submit button as well.

**Solution 2**

If you want to send the all the previously submitted values of "Society" because user may like to edit them again, use text inputs instead of hidden inputs. This will allow users to edit previously submitted data,

```
 <input type="text" name="varname%{status1.count}" value="varvalue">
```

**UPDATE**

If you'd like other fields to be persistent across multiple submits, you'd need to initialise your jsp form inputs with those submitted values each time.  You can use the same code as above (soln 2)

Comment: I'll try the solution 1 , thank  you very much for the answer! I'll let you know if I succeed